# $wpdb Fatal error

Tags: wordpress

I have problems in pointing to the database in Wordpress. I have tried to include global $wpdb and it does not work. And I have also done PHP include for the `wp-load.php`, `wp-db.php`, wp-config.php but still no fix.

It says,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\cv_test\searchresult_details.php
>   on line 47

Sorry, I'm a beginner in Wordpress development. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
    include_once('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-config.php');
include_once('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-load.php');
include_once('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php');

function retrieveClientDesc()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT client_desc FROM wp_client WHERE client_name =  'Cal'";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);



    for($i = 0; $i<=count($result); $i++)
    {
        $clientDesc = ($result[$i]->client_desc);
        echo $clientDesc;
    }

    print_r($result);
}
```

This is part of the codes. It keeps says my $result section has a fatal error.

Comment: Can you please place here your code ?

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem once and this is how i was able to solve it.

```
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

if(!isset($wpdb))
{
    //the '../' is the number of folders to go up from the current file to the root-map.
    require_once('../../wp-config.php');
    require_once('../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
```

Comment: Hmm... looks like the same problem again. The php file is located in my current activated theme folder. However the global $wpdb can be used in my search.php but not this file.

Comment: when do you call for this function? (at what point and how) and are you sure you included the files at the right location? (navigated relatively to the root and then include the files)

Comment: How can u find dynamically the path of this files?? as an when plugin gets online path wud differ according to theme directory...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you for your help. Managed to do a fix with this though.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able to, please accept your answer to make it easier for others to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Replace `global $wpdb;` with `$wpdb = new WPDB;`. The wpdb object wasn't yet initiated.

Comment: Sorry, looks like the codes not working.

Fatal error: Class 'WPDB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\cv_test\searchresult_details.php

Comment: Please check the path to your `wp-db.php` again. I never tried the way you include the file, but please try to use the relative path like `../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php` (maybe you have to modify my example) -- ***edit:*** or have a look at Michiel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parameter object from `$wpdb->get_results( $query );` and try with the code bellow

```
global $wpdb;
$table = "{$wpdb->prefix}client"
$query = "SELECT client_desc FROM wp_client WHERE client_name =  'Cal'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Answer (score 0):

> check your dir of the file and the pass your host credentials in
> WPDB($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost)

```
include_once( __DIR__. '/../../../../wp-config.php');
include_once( __DIR__. '/../../../../wp-load.php');
include_once( __DIR__. '/../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
class Myclass{
 function anyname(){
    $wpdb = new WPDB('root', '', 'wp_hopper', 'localhost');
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table", OBJECT );
    print_r($results) ;
 }
}
```